# PHP set_time_limit() does not work, safemode is off

Tags: php

I try to disable the time limit in an PHP script by

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

but it does not work; the script is still aborted after the system default of 30 seconds. The `max_execution_time` setting - as displayed by `phpinfo()` after `set_time_limit(0)` - still shows 30 seconds for both Master and Local value. It also shows that Safe Mode is Off.

Do you have any idea what goes wrong? It's PHP 5.3.3 <s>(cli)</s> running on CentOS 6.2 with Apache 2.2.15.

Comment: Are you on shared hosting or on a dedicated server ?

Comment: It is a virtual host on a dedicated server. I have root access to the virtual host.

Comment: Your server might have disabled the `set_time_limit()` function via the Suhosin Hardened PHP patch.

Comment: I don't think set_time_limit has any bearing when running CLI.  Also see: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37306

Comment: Sorry, "cli" information was wrong (I just looked for PHP version on the command line). The script is called via Apache PHP module.

Comment: Suhosin patch is not installed - it would appear on the phpinfo() page.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve the problem now. The reason was

```
php_admin_value max_execution_time "30"
```

... within the *virtual host* configuration. If set there, the time limit cannot be overridden by a PHP script. And the solution is to set it either in the php.ini instead of Apache config - that allows override ...

```
max_execution_time = 30
```

or to define exceptions for certain directories within the apache config, e.g.

```
<Directory /path/to/my/scripts>
  php_admin_value max_execution_time "600"
</Directory>
```

I also tried to define exceptions for single files using the <Files> directive, but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I was uploading a CSV file with lots of rows to process and it was max_input_time the problematic value.
The solution is quite easy:

ini_set('max_input_time', $yourDesiredValue);

$yourDesiredValue should be equal or bigger than max_execution_time.