# asterisk agi loop not working

Tags: loops, asterisk, agi

I am trying to have my php script loop 10 times when a call is made, but for some reason it only executes once and then it hangup/dies/exit. Any kind of insight I can get on this is greatly appreciated.

```
 for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
ob_implicit_flush(true);
require_once('phpagi.php');

$agi = new AGI();
$agi->answer();


  list ($id,$number,$callerid) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select `called`,`tollfree`,`callerid` from `avotfmaster`.`cdr` where `pbx`='0' order by `mins` desc, rand() limit 1",$xb));

if($id) {

$agi->set_callerid("$callerid");
$agi->exec('DIAL',"SIP/31282200*$number@sip.abc.com,40,L(60000)");


$gwopt_dtmf = $agi->get_data('confirm', 3000, 1);

if($gwopt_dtmf['result']==1)
        {
mysql_query("UPDATE `avotfmaster`.`cdr` SET `pbx`='1' WHERE `number`='$number'",$xb);


        } else {
        mysql_query("UPDATE `avotfmaster`.`cdr` SET `pbx`='2' WHERE `number`='$number'",$xb);
$agi->verbose("I will go ahead and mark this number already scanned and tested");

}

}
}
```

Comment: I noticed that If I reduce the talk time for the dial command, than the loop works fine... if anything is a minute or longer it kills my loop.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to call things like Dial, basically anything that ties your script up for an undetermined (or possibly long) amount of time, from a PHPAGI script.

System resources are not released until after the script ends.
For this reason there is a maximum script execution duration command in PHP, I bet your script runs longer than the default allowed amount of time (on most calls) and the script gets terminated.

See this answer for clues:
[PHP set_time_limit() does not work, safemode is off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094839/php-set-time-limit-does-not-work-safemode-is-off)

Comment: this is a very good point - I will try to "allow" my php script execution time longer...

Comment: If performance is at all an issue (I'm not sure what your script is used for) then it would be best to use the script to fetch the number, etc. that you need and pass it back to the dialplan as a variable and do the dial from there, gather your response and pass it to the (or some other) script for processing.
You could utilize a variable and pass it back and forth for a counter as well to keep track of your iterations.

As stated: I don't know if performance is an issue or not, if it's not then don't worry about it :-)

Comment: Forgot to mention: if you do it as described above then the time_limit won't be any issue anymore either.

Answer (score 0):

Please read documentation for Dial.

If you need control AFTER that function, you need add "g" key to options.

Comment: I have added: g after the timeout and it still does not loop: $agi->exec('DIAL',"SIP/31282200*$number@sip.abc.com,40,L(60000),g");

Comment: Because you reading docs bad. you need add g in same param, i.e before L. You not need add more commas.

Comment: i'm doing a loop, not trying to have asterisk follow what is next in my agi script....